# PopViewController not popping view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, xcode3.2

My top level view immediately Pushes my SplashView in it's ViewWillAppear method.  In some conditions, the SplashView pushes an additional view, which is properly popped.  When this occurs the Top Level view never appears.

However, the code in the Top Level is running (it has a timer that occurs every minute which writes to the log).  And if I trap it in Debug I can see the code executing.  Additionally, in the Top Level ViewDidAppear if I log the `[self navigationController].visibleViewController.nibName` the name of the Top Level appears.

If I don't do the Push in the SplashView everything works fine.

The app is forced into Landscape mode, and each ViewController contains `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);` for the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method.

I'm baffled and don't know what to do next.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

While I did not exactly determine why this was occurring, I have resolved the problem.  Here are some things I noticed in further debugging:

- I noticed the message `wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003` in the log.  Scanning blogs on this didn't help me much, but it led further down the path.  References to it showed issues with UIAlertView, which I did have in the Splash view.
- I added ViewDidAppear logic to the Splash view, then found this was getting called twice!  I then added logic to act on this only once and my problem was solved!

So apparently there is some quirk with the View getting called twice that was creating my initial issue.  References I found implied this was an 'old' OS issue, but I am using xCode 3.2.3 and SDK 4.0.2, so maybe it's back!  Gee, I don't recall it doing this with SDK 4.0.1!